# Unable to get .htaccess RewriteRule to work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a URL rewrite rule to work using .htaccess. Mod_rewrite is enabled and I have managed to get a 301 redirect to work (from /beta to /Beta/) so I know the .htaccess is able to work.

Basically I'm trying to get /Beta/Page.php?id=page&tab=services&tabid=tab1 to become /page/services (and ideally leave out the tabid if it's not going to break the site removing it).

The code I'm working with currently is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/Beta/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /Beta/Page.php?id=$1&tab=$2&tabid=$3

redirect 301 /beta http://www.example.com/Beta/
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading slash:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(Beta)/[^.]+\.php\?id=([^&]+)&tab=([^\s&]*)&tabid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^Beta/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /Beta/Page.php?id=$1&tab=$2&tabid=$3 [L,QSA]
```

This will externally redirect:

`/Beta/Page.php?id=page&tab=services&tabid=tab1`

to

`/Beta/page/services/tab1`

and rewrite same URI internally.

Also `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm afraid it's still not having any effect though. I'm still getting http://www.example.com/Beta/Page.php?id=page&tab=services&tabid=tab1

Comment: What did you expect instead of: `http://www.example.com/Beta/Page.php?id=page&tab=services&tabid=tab1` ?

Comment: http://www.example.com/Beta/page/services/tab1 (although I would like to not have the last variable ('tabid') if possible, although I'm not sure if that would mess up the page

Comment: Oh ok got it. If `tabid` is taken out then will get empty tabid in `/Beta/Page.php` will that work?

Comment: It's changing the URL but I'm getting a 404 error. I'm getting http://www.example.com/Beta/page/services/TabName1. I've also got URLs which don't contain variable 3 (tabid) and some that only contain variable 1 (id). Would I need to write different rules for these?

Comment: This will internally load: `/Beta/Page.php?id=page&tab=services&tabid=TabName1` Is that not a valid URI?

Comment: Yea that should work. One of the URLs that works when I revert back to the original htaccess is: /Beta/Page.php?id=hairdressers&tab=services&tabid=HairTab1 Another is /Beta/Page.php?id=about to give you a couple of examples

Comment: Well all those different URIs can be supported but isn't that going well beyond the stated problem in question? Wouldn't it be better that you build those simple rules based on my answer?

Comment: Apologies, what I meant by giving these examples was that I have URLs with and without variables 2&3 but that the original URL we discussed is still creating the error: "The requested URL /Beta/hairdressers/services/HairTab1 was not found on this server."

Comment: No worries, how should `/Beta/hairdressers/services/HairTab1 ` be internally rewritten to? Should that be: `/Beta/Page.php?id=hairdressers&tab=services&tabid=HairTab1` Will `Page.php` always be there?

Comment: With just above rules in my .htaccess when I request `/Beta/hairdressers/services/HairTab1` it gets interally rewritten to:  `/Beta/Page.php?id=hairdressers&tab=services&tabid=HairTab1`